# generate push notification ssl certificate and provision using new apple panel for development?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

using [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) link i try to make push notification apps .

but, this used old apple panel for generate ssl and provision certificate.

any one generate ssl and provision using new apple panel?

below step for generate ck.pem

> 1) $ openssl x509 -in aps_developer_identity.cer -inform der -out
>   PushChatCert.pem
>
> 2) $ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in PushChatKey.p12
>
> Enter Import Password:
>
> MAC verified OK
>
> Enter PEM pass phrase:
>
> Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
>
> 3) $ cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem
>
> 4) $ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
>
> Trying 17.172.232.226...
>
> Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
>
> Escape character is '^]'.

is this correct step?

please help me......

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the [Provisioning and Development](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) guide. They haven't modified it for the new `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` page (which replaced the `iOS Provisioning Portal`) yet, but it doesn't make much difference.

In the following screen click on `Identifiers` :

[image]

Then click on the relevant App ID (or create a new one if it doesn't exist).

Then click `Edit`.

Then make sure the check box next to `Push Notifications` is enabled (check it if it's not).

Then click `Create Certificate...` for either `Development` or `Production`.

The rest of the process should be identical to the way it was before the portal change, so you can either use the instructions in the link I provided, or instructions from other tutorials (such as the one in the link you provided).