# Django Push Notification to IOS

Tags: ios, django, ssl

I am using [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ios-notifications/0.1.5) library to implement django push notification , But while setting up it demands for certificate as well as private key content to add into admin panel of that.

```
----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am able to get certificate content by **openssl x509 -text -in cert.pem** command. But How do I obtain private key of certificate? If we cant obtain private key , What to write there. or please suggets me any other library which is easy to use..

Comment: this link might be useful http://ihackthati.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/setting-up-push-notification-in-an-ios-chat-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the related link in the blog entry you posted?

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

It explains that you need to set up an SSL certificate to make use of push notifications:

> You need to make a new App ID and provisioning profile for each app that uses push, as well as an SSL certificate for the server. You do this at the iOS Provisioning Portal.

Here is a related question:

- [Generate .pem file Used to setup Apple PUSH Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification)
- [generate push notification ssl certificate and provision using new apple panel for development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034968/generate-push-notification-ssl-certificate-and-provision-using-new-apple-panel-f)